# password_verify can't verify password_hash with Bcrypt

Tags: php, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I am having some problems getting `password_verify` to confirm my hashed password.
This is my login:

```
if (isset($_POST["login-button-front"]))
{
    // IF VALUE IS GIVEN
    if (isset($_POST["user-password"]) && ($_POST["user-email"])){
        $user_email = $_POST["user-email"];

        // QUERY DATABASE TO VERIFY LOGIN INFORMATION
        $query_password = $db->prepare("SELECT password, user_session FROM login WHERE email = :user_email");
        $query_password->execute(array(':user_email' => $user_email));
        $password_row = $query_password->fetchAll();

        // CHECK PASSWORD
        $password = $_POST["user-password"];
        $password_hash = $password_row[0]["password"];

        if(password_verify($password, $password_hash)){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $password_row['user_session'];
            require 'members.php';
        }
        // RESPOND IF WRONG INFORMATION GIVEN
        else{
            $login_wrong = "The username and/or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.";
            require 'front_page.php';
        }
    }
    // RESPOND IF NO INFORMATION GIVEN
    else{
        $login_wrong = "You must enter a valid username and password to login. Need an account? Register below.";
        require 'front_page.php';
    }
}
```

And this is my registration:

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: What is `'($_POST["user-password""])'`? Echo `$password` and see what it contains... and `'$password_row[0]["password"]'`. Echo `$password_hash`. And why do you create your own salt? It is completely unnecessary.

Comment: `$_POST["user-password"]` is echoing out to become `password`. Which is the correct password set in the login aswell. The other two are: `$2y$11$IFQ2XdQK14ERPpGQ70KowOOnEz1O7LmH2cKAERdoqitR569eWx9W2` and 
`$2y$11$IFQ2XdQK14ERPpGQ70KowOOnEz1O7LmH2cKAERdoqitR569eWx9W2`

Comment: The stored password in the database is also: `$2y$11$IFQ2XdQK14ERPpGQ70KowOOnEz1O7LmH2cKAERdoqitR569eWx9W2`

Comment: No. Check *what the variables contain*, not what you *think* they contain! The `$password` variable is a string that contains `($_POST["user-password""])`, and the `$password_hash` variable contains `$password_row[0]["password"]`. You are using single quotes, which do not interpolate variables. The second variable is also invalid, and needs to be wrapped in `{}`, i.e. `"{$password_row[0]["password"]}"`. You could also just not use strings, it is not necessary anyway.

Comment: Before you verify, use the following and make sure the values are correct: `var_dump($password, $user_email, $password_row, $password_hash);die;`

Comment: `var_dump` results are: `string(8) "password" string(21) "ingar1995@hotmail.com" array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$sLNV6ftIhh7RyaDkfSRPMuXuCouQCLp5U4eMC5tA04bJCefOjR/ea" [0]=> string(60) "$2y$10$sLNV6ftIhh7RyaDkfSRPMuXuCouQCLp5U4eMC5tA04bJCefOjR/ea" ["user_session"]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } } string(60) "$2y$10$sLNV6ftIhh7RyaDkfSRPMuXuCouQCLp5U4eMC5tA04bJCefOjR/ea"`

Comment: Nope. The code in your question would **not** produce that output. Please update the code in your question to the code that you are really using.

Comment: Updated my code: It's what I get as output.

Comment: Again, why are you putting variables into single quotes?! `'$password_hash'` will just give you `'$password_hash'`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76782/discussion-between-gjert-i-gjersund-and-sverri-m-olsen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over all my details, removed single and double quotes. Aswell as made sure there was no fetching errors. This was my working code:

```
if (isset($_POST["login-button-front"]))
{
    // IF VALUE IS GIVEN
    if (isset($_POST["user-password"]) && ($_POST["user-email"])){
        $user_email = $_POST["user-email"];

        // QUERY DATABASE TO VERIFY LOGIN INFORMATION
        $query_password = $db->prepare("SELECT password, user_session FROM login WHERE email = :user_email");
        $query_password->execute(array(':user_email' => $user_email));
        $password_row = $query_password->fetchAll();

        // CHECK PASSWORD
        $password = $_POST["user-password"];
        $password_hash = $password_row[0]["password"];

        if(password_verify($password, $password_hash)){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $password_row[0]['user_session'];
            require 'members.php';
        }
        // RESPOND IF WRONG INFORMATION GIVEN
        else{
            $login_wrong = "The username and/or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.";
            require 'front_page.php';
        }
    }
    // RESPOND IF NO INFORMATION GIVEN
    else{
        $login_wrong = "You must enter a valid username and password to login. Need an account? Register below.";
        require 'front_page.php';
    }
}
```

I ended up hashing using this:

```
$password_options = ['cost' => 11,'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22,MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),];
$password = password_hash($_POST['password1'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $password_options);
```

Comment: As Sverry already mentioned, it would be better to omit the salt parameter: `$password_options = ['cost' => 11];`, the function password_hash() will solve the problem better.